# .NET/MySQL Connector: Certificate Store Location

Tags: .net, mysql, ssl-certificate, mysql-connector

Trying to use a certificate that's not in "CurrentUser" (the Current User > Personal > Certificates store), but in the Computer certificate store.  The MySQL documentation only references the MySQL tutorial, which uses CurrentUser in it's example, but I can't find a list of actual, valid certificate location string values.  I tried "CurrentComputer" but that threw a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

[Found it](http://mysql-connector-net.sourcearchive.com/documentation/6.4.3-1/namespaceMySql_1_1Data_1_1MySqlClient_af5d0cd3d5250513841ef8de1e504ecad.html#af5d0cd3d5250513841ef8de1e504ecad).

Answer (score 0):

Valid values are `None`, `CurrentUser`, and `LocalMachine`.

In the .NET Connector's source file [MySql.Data/Provider/Source/MysqlDefs.cs](http://lists.mysql.com/commits/87374?f=plain):

```
public enum MySqlCertificateStoreLocation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Do not use certificate store
    /// </summary>
    None,
    /// <summary>
    /// Use certificate store for the current user
    /// </summary>
    CurrentUser,
    /// <summary>
    /// User certificate store for the machine
    /// </summary>
    LocalMachine
}
```